# Is it possible to validate a UUID in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, validation

How can I check that a `uuid` is valid in Solidity? Is there a library or anything to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for my misunderstand.

In Solidity, there isn't a built-in way to handle or check UUIDs (unique identifiers often used in databases).

Usually, a UUID looks like a string of letters and numbers, separated by hyphens, like this: "550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000". But in Solidity, you can't easily check if a string like this is a valid UUID.

One simple way to check, however, is to see if the string is 36 characters long (including the hyphens), which all UUIDs should be. Here's a simple function that does that:

```
function isUuid(string memory uuid) public pure returns (bool) {
    // UUID should be 36 characters long
    return bytes(uuid).length == 36;
}
```

This function only checks the length of the UUID, not its structure or whether it contains the right characters. A more thorough check would be more complex and might be too expensive to run on the Ethereum network.

Answer (score 0):

I am Ari Setiawan and a senior software engieer.

Please check this for your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53847404/how-to-check-uuid-validity-in-python

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do this in Solidity, not Python. Do you know if there is a library for that?